# Work around compiler bug

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, compiler-bug

I we have big computation geometry library. There is a problem in it's kernel. We have definitions scalar taits, and helper accesors in form of free functions, to simply write `cg::epsilon<T>()` instead of `cg::scalar_traits<T>::epsilon`. But problem that under vs2008 and vs2010 it sometimes argues that it could not deduce template parameter for `T` in `cg::epsilon<T>`. On other compilers in LWS works fine.

Reduced version to reproduce:

```
namespace cg
{

template<class S>
S epsilon();

template<>
double epsilon<double>() {return 1;}
template<>
float epsilon<float>() {return 1;}

template<class S>
bool eq(S a, S b, S eps = cg::epsilon<S>())
{
   return true;
}

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   cg::eq(0.0, 0.0);
   cg::eq(0.0f, 0.0f);
   return 0;
}
```

Are there some workarounds to make accessors work?

PS: We using `cg::scalar_traits<S>::epsilon()`, that helps, where error occurs, but that too much verbose

Research:
Even declarated as

```
template<class S>
bool eq(S a, S b, S eps = cg::epsilon<double>())
```

compiler complains that he could not deduce S for cg::epsilon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the compiler is using the defaulted parameter `S eps = cg::epsilon<S>()` in the deduction of `S`. For this, it needs to look at the declaration of `cg::epsilon<S>()` but at this time it doesn't know `S` yet.

A workaround is avoiding the default value for the third parameter and add two different overloads: the first takes three arguments (`a`, `b` and `eps`) and the second takes only two (`a` and `b`). The latter gets `eps` from `cg::epsilon<S>()` (at this time `S` has already been deduced) and delegates the call to the former as the below code shows:

```
template<class S>
bool eq(S a, S b, S eps)
{
    return true;
}

template<class S>
bool eq(S a, S b)
{
    S eps = cg::epsilon<S>();
    return eq(a, b, eps);
}
```

Comment: Your guesses sound realistic. But writing wrappers is worse than use `cg::scalar_traits<S>::epsilon`. And also, if you are right, why using traits does not trigger that error?

Comment: @kassak: I would also prefer not writing the wrapper and use a default parameter exactly as you did (I believe your code is standard compliant). Writing the wrapper is an unwanted workaround :-(. I don't understand what you mean by "using traits does not trigger that error" but, anyway, I cannot tell exactly what is going on since I can't see Visual Studio's code ;-) I can only guess.

Comment: Yep I understand. By "using traits does not trigger that error" I meant that using `cg::scalar_traits<S>::epsilon()` instead `cg::epsilon<S>()` does not trigger that error, but it is too verbose =( `cg::epsilon` just returns `cg::scalar_traits<S>::epsilon()` and was made to make code clearer. Because `cg::epsilon<S>()` is not only shorter it is what it is -- epsilon of type S